# how to import a block of a template in jinja2

Tags: python, templates, frontend, jinja2

I want to use `jinja2` to design a template that will be rendered as an article whose chapters and sections should be combined freely. So I create a `base.html` as a skeleton. The problem is that the chapters and sections contain some reusable table and image elements, and if I use these elements as 'macro', then it will be difficult to use chapters and sections as 'macro' too. But if I use chapters and sections as 'block', how can I import 'block' into the skeleton? And some local variables must be passed into chapters and sections.

Here is an example of my script. The script reads config.json and turns it into a dict to pass to the base.html for rendering. The actual number of chapters and sections are much more than that I represent in the example, with multiple paragraphs, and the number of type of components too.

```
#config.json
{"templates":[
        {"title":"chapter1",
        "children":[
                {"title":"chapter1_1","template":"template1.html","block":"block1"},
                {"title":"chapter1_2","template":"template2.html","block":"block1","parameter":{"note":"hello world"}},
        ]},
        {"title":"chapter2","template":"template1.html","block":"block2","parameter":{"note":"blabla"}}
]}


#base.html
{% from "component.html" import common_table as common_table with context %}
{% from "component.html" import common_img as common_img with context %}
{%- for chapter in chapter_list %}
        {%- set ch_loop = loop %}
        <h2>{{ ch_loop.index }}&nbsp;{{ chapter.title }}</h2>
        {%- if chapter.children %}
                {%- for section in chapter.children %}
                        <h3>{{ ch_loop.index }}.{{ loop.index }}&nbsp;{{ section.title }}</h3>
                        {% import section.template as template with context %}
                        {% set parameter=section.parameter %}
                        {{ template.blocks[section.block] }}
                {%- endfor %}
        {%- else %}
                {% import chapter.template as template with context %}
                {% set parameter=chapter.parameter %}
                {{ template.blocks[chapter.block] }}
        {%- endif %}
{%- endfor %}

#template1.html 
{% block block1 %}
        I am block 1
        {{ common_table(id="table1",head="nohead")  }}
        {{ common_img(src="css/icon/icon1.png")  }}
{% endblock %}

{% block block2 %}
        I am block 2
        {{ common_img(src="css/icon/icon2.png")  }}
        {% if parameter.note=="blabla" %}
                {{ "blabla~blabla~" }}
        {% endif %}
{% endblock %}

#component.html
{% macro common_table(id, name,note, head="onehead") %}
        {% if name %}
                <b class="tablename">{{ name }}</b>
        {% endif %}
        <table id="{{ id }}" class=" {{ head }}"></table>
        {% if note %}
                 <p class="tablenote">{{ note }}</p>
        {% endif %}
{% endmacro %}

{% macro common_img(src, alt, name) %}
        <img  src="{{ src }}" alt="{{ alt }}">
        {% if name %}
                <b class="imgname">{{ name }}</b>
        {% endif %}
{% endmacro %}
```

I searched and found that the template object in script seems to have 'blocks' attribute, so I tried to import template files as an object and use '.blocks' to get the block attribute of template object, but it gave me an error as following:

```
jinja2.exceptions.UndefinedError: 'jinja2.environment.TemplateModule object' has no attribute 'blocks'
```

I checked the code of jinja2 and found that the imported template object is 'TemplateModule' class, different from the 'Template' class in script, and the 'TemplateModule' class doesn't seem to have 'blocks' attribute, even doesn't export blocks .

So how can I import a block of a template ? Or should I change my jinja2 statements?

Comment: Why not try it out first, then ask specific questions about your attempts?

Comment: @Martijn Pieters  I have tried to use block to put my chapters and sections, but got an error. Please see my question again, I edit it with an example.